# Hydrogen relativistic energy levels: Why is this operator equivalent to this matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin, dirac-equation

I am trying to understand the derivation of the relativistic energy levels for the Hydrogen following the annex 2.2 of this [notes](http://porthos.ist.utl.pt/ftp/textos/itc.pdf).

Until the equation below I could follow the reasoning:

$$\left [-\left (\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right ) + \frac{1}{r^2}(L^2 - \alpha ^2\mp\alpha i  \mathbf {\sigma\cdot\hat{r}}) - \frac{2\alpha E}{r}-(E^2 - m^2)  \right ]\psi_\pm = 0$$

Where as far I understand, the angular part of the Laplacian in spherical coordinates was replaced by the operator $L^2$.

But then the operator
$(L^2 - \alpha ^2 \mp \alpha i  \mathbf {\sigma\cdot\hat{r}})$ is said to be equivalent to the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
(j+1/2)(j+3/4)-\alpha^2 &  \mp i\alpha\\
\mp i\alpha & (j-1/2)(j+1/2)-\alpha^2
\end{bmatrix}

$\mathbf {\sigma\cdot\hat{r}}$ seems 2 times the spin operator for the direction of the unit vector, that returns eigenvalue $1$. But why it is placed off diagonal in the matrix?

And why $l(l+1)$, the eigenvalues of $L^2$ are replaced by two different eigenvalues of $J^2$, and placed at the diagonal positions?

Comment: Possibly $\sigma\cdot\hat r=\sigma_z\cos\theta+\sigma_x\sin\theta\cos\phi+\sigma_y\sin\theta\sin\phi$, which is not diagonal since the $\sigma$’s are not all diagonal.  The possible values of $j$ when coupling $\ell\otimes 1/2$ are $j=\ell\pm 1/2$...

Comment: *But why it is placed off diagonal in the matrix?* See (A.42) for the matrix elements of $\vec\sigma\cdot\hat r$.

Comment: @G. Smith According to the matrix, (and A.42), the unit vector seems to be oriented in the xy plane, so that $cos(\theta) = 0$ and $sin(\theta) = 1$(see also comment of ZeroTheHero). I can't see why.

Answer (score 0):

The operator is replaced by the matrix, because one switches from an equation for general wave function to that for a solution with a particular angular momentum. This step is like in the non-relativistic treatment. The difference is that in the relativistic case the orbital momentum, $L^2$, does not commute with the Hamiltonian... but the total angular momentum, $J^2$, does!